# Multiple Inheritance Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have encountered an issue which I cannot seem to overcome.

I am creating classes which are responsible for part of the functionality to make a Blackjack game. The issue I am encountering is that I cannot seem to access'single_card' variable in class 'GetValue'. single_card is returned from a method in the Deck class but I cannot seem to access it in the GetValue class.

I have been researching multiple inheritance with no luck, can anyone help me spot where I might be going wrong and help educate me on how to fix the issue.

Current Error:
line 40, in **init__Card.__init**(self)
TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'suit' and 'rank'

Many thanks in advance!

P.S - I am new to user on stackoverflow so apologies if my question asking skills are not that great!

Code below:
'''

```
values = {'Two': 2, 'Three': 3, 'Four': 4, 'Five': 5, 'Six': 6, 'Seven': 7, 'Eight': 8, 'Nine': 9, 'Ten': 10,
          'Jack': 10,'Queen': 10, 'King': 10, 'Ace': 11}

class Deck():

    def __init__(self):
        suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs']
        ranks = ['Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
        self.deck = []  # start with an empty list
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit, rank))

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def __str__(self):
        deck_comp = ""
        for card in self.deck:
            deck_comp += '\n'+ card.__str__()
        return "The deck has: "+deck_comp

    def deal(self):
        self.single_card = self.deck.pop()
        return self.single_card

class Card():

    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank+" of "+self.suit

class GetValue(Deck, Card):

    def __init__(self):
        Deck.__init__(self)
        Card.__init__(self)
        self.cardtype = Deck.single_card.split()
        self.cardval = values.get(self.cardtype[0])
        print(self.cardval)

mydeck = Deck()
print(mydeck.deal())
myval = GetValue()
```

'''

Comment: GetValue should get the single_card from the deal method, read the first word in the string and find the value associated with that word in the values dictionary above. I got it working outside of a class but implementing it into a class hasn't seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that value relates to the numeric value corresponding to a card's rank, so it's an attribute of a card.  So you could give `Card` a `get_value` method that returns the value:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + " of " + self.suit

    def get_value(self):
        return values[self.rank]

mydeck = Deck()
card = mydeck.deal()
print(card)
print(card.get_value())
```

Another approach might be to pass value to `Card.__init__`, so it can be accessed as a simple attribute.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        self.value = value

card = Card('Hearts', 'three', 3)
print(card.value)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I can see now that I was massively overcomplicating something which was quite simple. This works perfectly thank you! Thank you everyone for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You should add `self.deal()` before trying to access `single_card` in the init method of `GetValue`.

`print(mydeck.deal())` is affecting a different instance of `Deck` which is not a part of `myval`

Comment: Hi, I have added self.deal() in the init method but unsure if I have implemented it correctly. 'class GetValue(Deck, Card):

    def __init__(self):
        Deck.__init__(self)
        self.deal()
        self.cardtype = self.deal.single_card.split()
        self.cardval = values.get(self.cardtype[0])
        print(self.cardval)' with a error code of self.cardtype = self.deal.single_card.split()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'single_card' @Jolbas